JQuery click event in bimsync api
i am trying to select objects by mouseclick in bimsyncs 3d viewer api.
the documentation suggests something like
$('.viewer').bind('viewer.select', function(event, selected) {
    console.log(selected);
});

where the documentation makes no difference for viewer.select and viewer.click
when trying to implement the click event i fail. my code:
viewer3d.loadModelsFromToken(viewer_url).then(() => {
  console.log("Model loaded successfully");
  var selectedObject = $('.viewer3d').bind('click', function(event) {
    console.log("Selected object:", selectedObject);

the result is  that the selectedObject is my viewer object but not the selected 3dobject in the viewer.
any help highly appreciated

bind() has been deprecated for many years, you should be using on().

.bind() returns the jQuery collection you're binding the handler to, as part of the fluent interface. It allows you to write things like $(selector).bind(...).addClass("newclass").

You need to set selectedObject in the event listener that selects the object, not when you're binding the listener.

@Barmar thank you for your hint, unfortunately i am too much a nooby to understand where you want to guide me!

Unfortunately I don't know anything about bimsync, so I can't provide a more detailed answer.
